# Load millions of rows using impdp into a table in parallel mode with trigger installed (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, database-trigger, impdp

I am trying to load millions of Rows using impdp into a Table in parallel mode:

impdp .... parallel=10

The trigger On that table "before insert trigger" should replace some values.

Is there any way to execute the trigger in parallel mode too?

Comment: triggers will fire for each and every event that is applicable - doesn't matter if it's a single process issuing inserts or 10 processes issuing inserts on 1 or many tables, unless of course you've disabled said trigger

Comment: With a large scale of data your question should be *how to get rid of the trigger?*. In other words, having a trigger on the table you *de facto* don't care about performance (you inhibit the direct mode load), so the parallel mode should not really matter.

Comment: Unfortunately the trigger is needed

Comment: Can't you disable the trigger, "replace some values" directly in SQL, load the table and enable the trigger again?

Comment: Paste in the code of your trigger, and we'll see if we can come up with workarounds for you

Answer (score 0):

First, disable the trigger. Then, update using `MERGE INTO`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26397715)

Comment: @ysf: They _are_ the author. They are providing an explanation of how they solved their own problem.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure your problem out. Can you provide more details on how you accomplished this in order to help future readers? Including the syntax for disabling the trigger in Oracle would be useful, for instance, and possibly the basic structure of the `MERGE INTO` statement. Remember, the ultimate goal of this site is not only to help you find answers, but also help future readers learn from those answers.